# DataGridView image column issue on sorting

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a *DataGridView* that has an `image` column. The `image` address is read from one of the cells of the same row and then shown.

When I sort the columns the images go away.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in *C#*. Data is retrieved from anaccess database using *oledb* methods.

**Code that fills `image` columns is below:**

```
Image Image_File = Image.FromFile("d:\\2.jpg");

DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill; 

for (int i=0;i < info_Grid.RowCount;i++)  
{ 

   if (Info_Grid.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value !=" ")  
   {  
       Image_File =  Image.FromFile(Info_Grid.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());  
       Info_Grid.Rows[i].Cells["Image_Col"].Value = Image_File;  
   }                                                                              
}  
Info_Grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

---

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Really need more details here. Code , technology used , context ?

Comment: simply show an image that its address stored in one of the cells for each row of gridview. and if i sort grid view by clicking on the column header, image not shown any more. 
detail about what?

Comment: What is the line doing the sorting ? Put a comment beside so that it is clear.

Comment: you misunderstand, sorting is not something that i coded, just default sorting of DataGridView ! that can be disabled with a line of code, but I don't want do that. i need that. am I clear?

Comment: Can you trigger it manually after disabling it ? Maybe the result would be different.

Comment: I try it but result is the same, and after sorting images didn't showed any more. please help me. I need to sort.
really appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I was troubled by this this morning. When sorting a dataviewgrid, all the images added at runtime are lost. Something about the built-in DataGridView sorting breaks this.

**Example**

[image: DGV as Bound]  >> 
[image: DGV after sorting]

For me, I just added my image add code to the DGV.`Sorted` event. It somehow feels wrong to have to do this, but I do not know why these images are lost on sort in the first place.

```
  private void dgvChecks_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvChecks.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells["Valid"].Value.ToString() == "True")
                    row.Cells[0].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.check;
                else
                    row.Cells[0].Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.delete;
            }           
    }
```